# Change select to ui-select with ngRepeat filters

Tags: html, angularjs, select, angular-filters, ui-select

I am using plain HTML select boxes to filter ngRepeat results, like so:

```
<select ng-model="theFilter.choice">
    <option value="">Any</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select>

<select ng-model="theFilter.otherChoice">
    <option value="">Any</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select>

<div class="col-xs-12" 
     ng-repeat="item in options | filter: { showMe: theFilter.choice, amIDeleted: theFilter.otherChoice }">
    <p>{{ item.showMe }}</p>
    <p>{{ item.amIDeleted }}</p>
</div>
```

This works as intended.  But, like we all know the styling of the Browser select box is not very nice, so I am trying to replace the normal select boxes with `ui-select` select boxes, but these select boxes do not work correctly.

[See plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/clXmMumHzjQPdRw9ozCr?p=preview)

When the ui-select is changed first, nothing happens.  But when the select box is selected first, the ui-select becomes available to use.  I can then use both `ui-select` and the HTML5 select box.  But I only want to use the `ui-select`.

My question is: Is there any way that I can use the `ui-select` instead of the normal select box to filter my results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/S1QUAANMHkkvBNgYEEmx?p=preview) example of ui-select with filter option of your example scenario:

**Controller:**

```
$scope.theFilter = { 
    showMe: $scope.options[0].showMe, 
    amIDeleted: $scope.options[0].amIDeleted  
};
```